# Boost::Asio peer-to-peer udp chat

Tags: c++, chat, boost-asio, p2p, broadcast

I'm writing peer-to-peer (it shouldn't have server - it's a task) program for exchanging text messages. It's a very tiny chat. Simply messages, nothing else. It's my 1st practice with Boost::Asio, therefore I've some questions.

My chat should be peer-to-peer as I said and it should use udp protocol. I think, the best way is to use broadcast. And the first problem: how can I learn about new connections?

Another problem is in sending message: I send it on broadcast address and then it spreads to all computers in local network. Is it right?

This code sends message and receives its back. Like an echo. Is it right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        ip::udp::socket socket(io_service,
            ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1555));
        socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

        ip::udp::endpoint broadcast_endpoint(ip::address_v4::broadcast(), 1555);

        boost::array<char, 4> buffer1;
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer1), broadcast_endpoint);

        ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;

        boost::array<char, 4> buffer2;
        std::size_t bytes_transferred = 
            socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer2), sender_endpoint);

        std::cout << "got " << bytes_transferred << " bytes." << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and Boost.Asio 1.71.

Usually this kind of task is accomplished by using multicast. Broadcast creates too much load on a network.

Basing on the [sender](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/multicast/sender.cpp) and [receiver](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/multicast/receiver.cpp) examples while combining both of them, you should open your socket on a multicast address, which represents a "chat room" and at the same time subscribe to that multicast group to receive the messages sent from other chat participants.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

constexpr std::uint16_t multicast_port = 30001;

class Peer {
public:
    Peer(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
         const boost::asio::ip::address& chat_room,
         const std::string& nickname)
        : socket_(io_context)
        , multicast_endpoint_(chat_room, multicast_port)
        , nickname_(nickname)
{

    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(chat_room, multicast_port);
    socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
    socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);
```

Note that we using reuse_address option, so you could test this example locally.

If you want to receive messages sent to multicast group, you have to subscribe to that multicast group:

```
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(chat_room));
```

And as you asked if you want to learn about new connections (though UDP is a connectionless protocol), you can send multicast welcome message:

```
auto welcome_message = std::string(nickname_ + " connected to the chat\n");

        socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(welcome_message), multicast_endpoint_,
                              [this](const boost::system::error_code& error_code, std::size_t bytes_sent){
            if (!error_code.failed()){
                std::cout << "Entered chat room successfully" << std::endl;
            }
        });
```

So, for now we have to establish two loops: first one will expect local user's input, send it to the multicast group and then waits for another user input, while the other one will listen for incoming UDP datagrams on a socket, print datagram's content on every datagram received and then return back to socket listening:

```
void do_receive(){
        socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(receiving_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
                              [this](const boost::system::error_code& error_code, std::size_t bytes_received){
            if (!error_code.failed() && bytes_received > 0){
                auto received_message_string = std::string(receiving_buffer_.begin(), receiving_buffer_.begin() + bytes_received);
                // We don't want to receive the messages we produce
                if (received_message_string.find(name_) != 0){
                    std::cout.write(receiving_buffer_.data(), bytes_received);
                    std::cout << std::flush;
                }
                do_receive();
            }
        });
    }
void do_send(){
    std::string nickname = nickname_;
    std::string message;
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
    std::string buffer = name.append(": " + message);
    socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, maximum_message_size_), multicast_endpoint_,
                       [this, message](const boost::system::error_code& /*error_code*/, std::size_t bytes_sent){
        std::cout << "You: " << message << std::endl;
        do_send();
    });
}
```

There we also invoke the same IO function in each completion handler to achieve the loop effect still looking like recursion.

For now, all we have to do is to publish each of the function call in the separate threads because of io_context.run() invocation blocking, otherwise one of our loops will block another one, so we call io_context.run() in each thread:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    boost::asio::thread_pool thread_pool(2);
    if(argc != 3){
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./peer <your_nickname> <multicast_address>" << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::address chat_room(boost::asio::ip::make_address(argv[2]));
    Peer peer(io_context, chat_room, argv[1]);

    boost::asio::post(thread_pool, [&]{
        peer.do_receive();
        io_context.run();
    });
    boost::asio::post(thread_pool, [&]{
        peer.do_send();
        io_context.run();
    });
    thread_pool.join();

    return 0;
```

}

Full source code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/humanzer0/9b85c5cc5f4a1ffe2a3acc6a66f64c4c).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30174047)

Comment: @Tomerikoo done. Is it good enough now?